# Change ng-bind and ng-model dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-ngmodel, ng-bind

i need help.
I have a project and i need duplicate html nodes dynamically. Those nodes have ng-bind and ng-model attributes like this:

```
<input class="quest_model" type="text" data-ng-model="quest">
<span ng-bind="quest" class="quest_bind"></span>
```

I can change this attributes whith Jquery like this:

```
quest.find("span.quest_bind").attr("ng-bind", "quest" + seq);
```

but, when i press a button to duplicate a node, the magic of angularJS(ng-bind) not happens.
anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Use a json object

```
$scope.quest = {
'this': 'some random value',
'that': 'some other value'
}
$scope.seq = 'this'
```

then all you have to do is reference the json object in your controller

```
<span ng-bind="quest[seq]" class="quest_bind"></span>
```

set the ng-model of the input to $scope.seq which will allow you to control what your span element is binded to.

```
<input class="quest_model" type="text" ng-model="seq">
```

So if you type "that" in your input box it will bind the span tag to **$scope.quest.that**, which equals **"some random value"**

Likewise, if you type "this" in your input box it will bind the span tag to **$scope.quest.this**, which equals **"some other value"**

Comment: Adding new data to your quest object will be extremely easy. to add a new entry named "quest1" you would just use $scope.quest.quest1 = "blah blah blah"

Comment: Then if you typed quest1 into your inputbox it would bind "blah blah blah" to your span element